# Could not write metadata for ‘/RemoteSystemsTempFiles’

Tags: eclipse

Como resolver este erro? Toda hora ele aparece no Eclipse.

> Could not write metadata for '/RemoteSystemsTempFiles'.
>   C:\Users\Josue\workspacejavaee.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\RemoteSystemsTempFiles.markers.snap
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode excluí-lo se quiser, não faz mal a outros projetos. Ele é criado pelo explorador de sistemas remotos que vem com o Eclipse.

Para evitar que se crie novamente (em um novo projeto), desative essa opção em: Em **Window-> Preferences** tipo '**Remote**'. Clique em **'Remote Systems View'** (Exibição de Sistemas Remotos) e desmarque a opção **'Reopen Remote Systems View to Previous State'** (Reabrir a Visualização de Sistemas Remotos para o Estado Anterior).
*Obs: Essa opção funcionou para mim*

**Outra opção (se não funcionar a anterior)**
Basta ir em Window -> Preferences -> General -> **'Startup and Shutdown'** (Inicialização e Desligamento) e desmarque **RSE UI**. Depois, você poderá remover a pasta e o Eclipse não irá recriá-la.

Post que me ajudou (na época)
[What is RemoteSystemsTempFiles in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627463/what-is-remotesystemstempfiles-in-eclipse)

Comment: Ismael, dentro do diretório org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects tem 3 pastas, sendo duas referente a dois projeto e 1 do servers. O que devo apagar neste diretório do erro?

Comment: Se a pasta RemoteSystemsTempFiles existir, delete-a, caso não, faça o procedimento da configuração no Eclipse.

Comment: Ismael, muito obrigado, por me ajudar! Segui suas orientações e consegui solucionar o problema. Abraços!

Comment: @JosueSantos Olá, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.